# LoopBack filtering for GET /projects

Tags: loopbackjs

With Project.find() or GET /projects I want to get only the current users projects. Where should this filtering be done? I've tried with acls in project.json:

```
"accessType": "*",
"principalType": "ROLE",
"principalId": "teamMember",
"permission": "ALLOW"
```

and a registered Resolver for that. But I can only get this to work for findById() or GET /projects/:id, not for listing all projects.

I've also tried as an observer in project.js:

```
Project.observe('access', function(ctx, next){
    ctx.query.where.memberId = 1;
    next();
});
```

etc ..

How is this supposed to be done? I've also studied Loopbacks tutorial on a similar case here: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Tutorial%3A+access+control

Although this is not what I am trying to do, I'm stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [where filter](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter) in your get method to achieve what you want. In your Project model you probably have userId. What you have to do is to add "where" filter with userId to your request

/projects?filter[where][userId]=1

, or if you want to use node API you can do it like this:

```
Project.find({
        where: {userId: 1}
    }, 
    function(err, projects){
        //do something with projects
     });
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to modify query on READ operation, then you need to use operation hooks. You were on the right track.

```
  Project.observe('access', function(ctx, next){
    ctx.query = {"where": {userId: 1}}; //define your query as needed
    next();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you A.Z, although I want this to be the default when a GET /projects is done. I don't want it to be possible to get any other projects than the ones a user is a member of